# Jquery modal plugin x close button partially hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying out the [jquery modal plugin](http://jquerymodal.com/) and I am following the example.

I have css and js linked and I have a div with some text in it and I have a link which is supposed to open that div and display the modal. However the x button in the top right corner of the modal is getting cut off. Any ideas why?

I am using bootstrap as well.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="content-delete" href="#overlay" rel="modal:open"> delete</a>
  <div id="overlay" style="display:none;">
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete this content?<a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pp34oazq/2/) example of this happening.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix with this one line:

```
.modal { overflow: initial; }
```

Bootstrap overrides this to hidden, so set it back with initial. This is a known issue with jquery-modal https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

The displayed css sets the close-modal element with a -ve offset for top and right.

```
.modal a.close-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12.5px;
    right: -12.5px;
```

You can set them to something +ve to fix this issue

Comment: I don't know what a -ve offset is. Can you perhaps post the code that would fix it and explain? perhaps an updated fiddle?

Comment: -ve was shorthand for negative.
Change your values for top to 0 and right to 0, or a positive integer such as 10px.
e.g.
    .modal a.close-modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;

Answer (score 0):

The position of the x button can be changed and updated using [css calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

this implies a fixed size of the .modal:

```
width: 500px;
height: 90px;
```

Instead, if you do not want a fixed modal you may do this computation when you show the modal itself, in the show method (I assume).

In this way the close button will be visible:

```
.modal a.close-modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: calc((100% - 90px - 12.5px) / 2);
        right: calc((100% - 500px - 12.5px) / 2);
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...") no-repeat 0 0;
 }
```

The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp34oazq/7/)

Comment: Thanks. that does work to make the close button visible but I would prefer to have it act like it does in [this](http://jquerymodal.com/) where the x button is not completely inside of the dialog box

Comment: @user3494047 I don't know if this other approach will help you. In any case, if you cannot use fixed size, you may always act inside the show method. Thanks so much.